# Why isn't gcloud available to /usr/bin/sh on Google Compute Engine instances?

Tags: shell, path, google-compute-engine, gcloud, coreos

I'm trying to write a unit file for my CoreOS (version 1185.5.0) instance running on Google Compute Engine. However, it involves invoking [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) via `/usr/bin/sh`, e.g. `/usr/bin/sh -c 'gcloud --version'`. The problem I face then is that /usr/bin/sh doesn't find gcloud: `/usr/bin/sh: gcloud: command not found`. I don't know why, as gcloud is available to me in my login shell.

Basically, how do I ensure that `/usr/bin/sh` can run `gcloud`?

### Edit:

`which` doesn't find `gcloud` in my login shell either:

```
$ which gcloud
which: no gcloud in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/bin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figure out where `gcloud` is (via `which gcloud`), and give the full path in `/bin/sh` invocations.

For example:

```
$ which gcloud
/home/myusername/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
$ sh -c '/home/myusername/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud version'
```

Comment: I thought of that too, but which doesn't find it either.

Answer (score 0):

In CoreOS, gcloud is a command alias:

$ alias gcloud
alias gcloud='(docker images google/cloud-sdk || docker pull google/cloud-sdk) > /dev/null;docker run -t -i --net=host -v /home/myusername/.config:/.config -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/doker.sock google/cloud-sdk gcloud'

This alias will install/run gcloud. Running gcloud is essentially:

$ docker run google/cloud-sdk gcloud help

Or as run by the above alias:

$ docker run -t -i --net=host -v /home/myusername/.config:/.config -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/doker.sock google/cloud-sdk gcloud